# Casting in C to access specific bytes in a variable

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I have a `void *` variable that is 8 bytes long, as all pointers are. I am working with addresses that are in 8 byte format because they are stored in pointers but are small enough to be represented in just 4 bytes. I want to make the first 4 bytes of the `void *` variable to be one address while the last 4 bytes are another address;

So if I have `void *p = 0x0000000000000000` and I have other pointers  `void *a = 0x12345678` and `void *b = 0x12345678` I would like to end with `void *p = 0x1234567812345678`

I am trying to do this with the following function:

```
void set_ptr(void *p, void *first_ptr, void *second_ptr){
   *(unsigned int *)(p) = (unsigned int)(first_ptr);
   *(unsigned int *)((char*)p + 4) = (unsigned int)(second_ptr);
}
```

Would this work or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `p = (void*)(((uint64_t)a << 32) | (uint32_t)b)`. But this is highly fragile and can have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Instead of `void*` use `uint64_t`: ... `uint64_t final = ((uint64_t)((uint32_t)0x12345678) << 32) + (uint32_t)0x12345678; /* thanks @EricPostpischil*/` Remember to #include <stdint.h>

Answer (score 1):

Use `memcpy`. Something like:

```
void f(void *p, const void *a, const void *b) {
    memcpy(&p, &a, 4);
    memcpy(((char *)p) + 4, &b, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, know that this will be very fragile and unportable. It won't work, obviously, if compiled for a processor with 32-bit pointers. But if you just want something that works on your machine, I would suggest defining a new type, like this:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t p1;
    uint32_t p2;
} DoublePointer;
```

Then you can access the two pointers easily as fields in the `DoublePointer` struct. And if you need to assign the struct to a single pointer, that's easy too:

```
DoublePointer doublePointer;
doublePointer.p1 = 0x12345678;
doublePointer.p2 = 0x12345678;
void *frankenpointer = (void*) *((uint64_t*) &dp);
```

Did I mention that this is fragile? I wouldn't recommend going down this path, or somebody will inherit this code and wish they had a different job.

Comment: `void *frankenpointer = (void *) doublepointer;`??? That's beyond fragile - it's casting a `struct Doublepointer` to a `void *`.  Offhand, that's a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, you're totally right. You have to first cast to a scalar. I've fixed that so it compiles. (And I still think this is a bad idea but am assuming there's some defensible reason for doing this that I haven't thought of.)